# Picasso Callback with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

I'm making an Android app with Kotlin, and need to use Picasso to download images. I saw this Java code below for setting animations to images, but I can't convert it to Kotlin, cause I don't know how to set Callback in "into" function.

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
       .load(imageUrl)
       .into(imageView, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        //set animations here

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        //do smth when there is picture loading error
                    }
                });
```

Can someone help me ?

My actual code :

```
Picasso.with(context)
       .load(url)
       .into(imageDiapo, com.squareup.picasso.Callback)
```

Comment: This is looks like `object: Callback{}` in Kotlin

Comment: In my case I was using CustomeImageView, I have replaced it with ImageView and working fine

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
Picasso.with(MainActivity::this)
       .load(imageUrl)
       .into(imageView, object: com.squareup.picasso.Callback {
                    override fun onSuccess() {
                        //set animations here

                    }

                    override fun onError(e: java.lang.Exception?) {
                        //do smth when there is picture loading error
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 16):

In Latest version `onError` recives an `Exception` as parameter and uses `get()` instead of `with()` :

```
  Picasso.get()
  .load(imageUrl)
  .into(imageView, object :Callback{
   override fun onSuccess() {
   Log.d(TAG, "success")
   }

   override fun onError(e: Exception?) {
   Log.d(TAG, "error")
   }
   })
```

and On the previous version

```
   Picasso.with(MainActivity::this)
   .load(imageUrl)
   .into(imageView, object: Callback {
                override fun onSuccess() {
                   Log.d(TAG, "success")
                }

                override fun onError() {
                  Log.d(TAG, "error")
                }
            })
```

Comment: Thanks was looking for this only

Answer (score 1):

Hi here are some different ways that Picasso provides:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(path).into(imageView);
```

2.create a new file inside our utils package, call it picasso.kt and fill it with simple code below:

```
 public val Context.picasso: Picasso
    get() = Picasso.with(this)
```

3. While this corresponds to the receiver object we can invoke following code on any Context:

```
picasso.load(path).into(imageView)
```

4. We can go further and extend ImageView class like:

   ```
   public fun ImageView.load(path: String, request: (RequestCreator) -> RequestCreator) {
   request(getContext().picasso.load(path)).into(this)    }
   ```